# Suddenly stopped getting push notification

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Suddenly my `iPhone` app stopped getting push notification.
I checked the server and the expiration date is valid. the app registering fine and send `token ID` without any problem.

What I noticed is that I have `"iPhone Production IOS push service: com.mypackage"`  not expandable, I mean without the private key. I cant remember maybe somehow I deleted it.

The question is if I sign the app for dis/AD-HOC with a provision that enables the push notification, with that push notification (not expandable) key I may have problems getting push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what iOS version you are using. But, if it used to work on iOS 7 and the issue started on iOS 8, maybe it is because of Apple change of their push notification API on iOS 8.

For more info you can look on:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html